# JDBC prepared statement - make a token null

Tags: insert, java, jdbc

So, I have an insert statement in a Java program I'm writing. Under some conditions, I want it to insert some values as null. However, before I can execute the statement, I have to set all of the tokens to values. How can I make it set something to null instead?

Edit:

Example:

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO DANIEL.UNIQUE_PHYSICIAN "
            + "(SOURCE_ID, ROOT_ID, SOURCE_TABLE, CONFIDENCE_IS_SAME,"
            + " IS_ROOT_PHYS, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, POSTAL_CODE) VALUES (?, ?"
            + ", 'STI.PHYSICIAN', 1, 0, ?"
            + ", ?, ?)";
```

Sometimes, I want to insert nothing for POSTAL_CODE (for example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29):

```
preparedStatement.setNull(8, Types.VARCHAR);
```

Although I have seen drivers that do not properly support that, in that case simply try:

```
preparedStatement.setString(8, null);
```